# how to write a function that takes keywords of different function

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, keyword-argument

I want to write a function that simply plots the data. How can I write the function in a way that it takes as arguments known keywords from `plt.plot`? For example:

```
def plot_data(x, y):
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.axvline(max(y))
```

Say I have 2 different data sets: I want to assign different `colors` and different `labels`.

The way I am doing it now is:

```
def plot_data(x, y, color=None, label=None):
    plt.plot(x, y, color=color, label=label)
    plt.axvline(max(y)) 

plt.plot(x1, y1, color='g', label='set1')
plt.plot(x2, y2, color='k', label='set2')
```

But what if I also want to assign different `linestyle`, different `linewidth`, different `markers`, ....

Is there a neat way to pass these `keywords` into the function instead of just writing them all?

```
def plot_data(x, y, color=None, label=None, ls=None, lw=None, marker=None):
    plt.plot(x, y, color=color, label=label, ls=ls, lw=lw, marker=marker)
    plt.axvline(max(y))
```

I can imagine something like:

```
def plot_data(x, y, **kwargs):
    plt.plot(x, y, **kwargs)
    plt.axvline(max(y))
```

Comment: I think you answered your own question with what you imagined?

Comment: yeah, but how would I call the function?

Comment: You'd call it like this: `plot_data(x, y, color=..., label=..., ls=...)` The keyword arguments are automatically packaged into a dictionary.

Comment: I get an error that color is not defined ....